# SQL: match time on several minutes

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I'm trying to match datetimes from two different tables.  Table A has a regular time (09:29:35).  Table B has a rounded time (09:30).

The time from table B could match the time from table A, or it could match the minute before due to rounding.

How can I match these times?  Or, how can I 'remove' the seconds from table A and round the minutes on that table as well?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Do you want to match both when rounded down and rounded up? Let's say Table B has 09:30. Which of these values in Table A do you want to represent a match? 09:29:35, 09:29:01, 09:27:00, 09:30:01, 09:30:59, 09:31:00. And does date matter also, or do you want to completely ignore the date? If you are ignoring date, why are you using DATETIME instead of TIME?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining better.  Yes I would want to match on all of those cases.  I do want to match on the date as well.

Comment: So do you want all times within one minute on either side, within 2 minutes on either side, something else? What about 09:31:59 and 09:32:00? Where is the cutoff?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused.  09:31:59 in table A would match 09:32 in table B and 09:32:14 in table A would also match 09:32 in table B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the seconds with a cast:

```
convert(varchar(16), getdate(), 120)
```

This chops the date after the seconds, f.e. `2011-06-30 19:50` (16 characters long.)  Adding or substracting minutes can be done with `dateadd`.

If you combine it in a join, you get something like:

```
select  *
from    TableA
join    TableB
on      convert(varchar(16), TableA.DateColumn, 120) between
        convert(varchar(16), dateadd(m,-1,TableB.DateColumn), 120)
        and convert(varchar(16), dateadd(m,1,TableB.DateColumn), 120)
```

Comment: It would be a shame if these columns have indexes on them. Converting them to a varchar renders the indexes useless and will cause table scans.

Comment: @Aaron, there isn't an index, but thanks for the explanation.  @Andomar - if I remove the seconds, will it round up or down?

Comment: Removing the seconds that way will truncate. If you convert to SMALLDATETIME to remove the seconds, it will round.

Comment: @divided: It will truncate (round down.)  One way to alter that is to add 90 seconds instead of 1 minute, which has the effect of rounding.  That's `dateadd(s,-90,...)`

Comment: converting to varchar when it isn't nessasary isn't really good sql

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM tableA a
JOIN tableb b
ON a.regulartime between dateadd(minute, -5, b.roundtime)
AND dateadd(minute, +5, b.roundtime)
```